# Infinite integral domain may not be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am in the beginning of studing of ring theory so let me ask the following question:

We know the following fact: *Finite integral domain is a field.*

What if we drop the assumption of finiteness? Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ which is a collection of polynomials $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots$ with coefficients from the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. If we define usual addition and multiplication of polynomials it is easy to check that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ is infinite integral domain. But it is not field since the element $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ is non-zero and has not multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Am I right?

Comment: Do you know where the name "integral domain" comes from?

Comment: @ArnaudD., I know the definition of integral domain but not where it comes from. It would be interesting to know that.

Comment: Your example is correct. But you have seen a simpler to describe infinite integral domain that is not a field much earlier in your studies. In grade school already (though it wasn't referred to as an integral domain at that point).

Comment: @RFZ To be more specific : do you have an idea what "integral" might refer to?

Comment: @ArnaudD., Good question! But I guess this is an object which consists of "integer" elements :) This is my opinion :/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, maybe you mean $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: @RFZ What examples of integral domains do you know?

Comment: No, a more elementary object.

Comment: What everybody is trying to say is that you're overthinking things.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @ArnaudD., For example, the set of integers

Comment: Dingdingdingdingdingding! Good job. Never easy to fill in a blind spot.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Indeed, my example was harder however, it's also the case. Thanks, dear Jyrki! P.S. I am a big fan of your post in MSE :)